# Powershell - Unable to create directory in Program Files and specify install path

Tags: powershell, scripting

I am trying to write a simple script but I am running into trouble when I try to create a directory in "C:\Program Files".

```
New-Item -Path "C:\Program Files\JHA" -ItemType Directory
```

When I do this, no directory is created. No error is thrown. I have admin privileges on my computer. Any advice?

Also, in this script I would like to run an installer and specify this path I created above as the directory it installs to. Is that possible? I read one post where the person was using `IMAGEDIR=` but someone said Powershell doesn't allow you to specify the installation folder.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Okay, apparently at some point my code worked and C:\Program Files\JHA\Install Directory was created. But now I get permission denied when I try. I wasn't getting that before, and I don't remember what code I used to create the full path. I will see how to elevate the script. That should fix the problem. Any suggestions on specifying an install directory?

Comment: Installing software means (in virtually all cases) you must be running as admin. You can create a dir in any location you have permissions to do so. This is not a PowerShell code issue. PowerShell does not control what this installer does. You have to pass the installer arguments correctly. Running external exes/installers like msi is a well-documtned thing. Proper quoting is mandatory when passing arguments.   [• PowerShell: Running Executables](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx)

Comment: Also try adding the `-Verbose` parameter to see what it says